# How to return an object's name instead of its value?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript objects have a "name : value" relationship.
I need a way to return an object's name instead of its value.

For example, if `animals[0].species` would return the value "feline",
how do I instead return the name "species"?

The function I'm writing requires me to check if an object's name is equal to
the input of the function before I return the value of that object.

I have searched stackoverflow and W3Schools for a solution, with no success.

```
var animals = [
{
    "animal": "cat",
    "species": "feline",
    "likes": "yarn",
    "dislikes" : "water"
},
{
    "animal": "dog",
    "species": "canine",
    "likes": "rubber balls",
    "dislikes": "thunder"
}
];


function lookUp(property){
  if (animals[0].property == "species") {
    return animals[0].species;
  }
}
lookUp("species");
```

Comment: Are you meaning to check if the property exists and if so return its value?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean to do.

Comment: It should be noted that you have an array of objects there defined in your code. This shouldn't really be called JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quotes around `species`

```
function lookUp(property) {
  if (animals[0].property === 'species') { // see the quotes ?
    return animals[0].species;
  }
}
```

That function is using the `animals` free variable and not very useful to you if you ever plan on using `lookUp` on any other object. By writing the function differently, you can make it much more versatile

```
function lookUp(object, property) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    return object[property];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Now look up a specific animal

```
lookUp(animals[0], 'species'); // => 'feline'
lookUp(animals[1], 'species'); // => 'canine'
lookUp(animals[2], 'species'); // => null
```

You can take this one step further by defining a higher-order procedure

```
function getSpecies(animal) {
  return lookUp(animal, 'species');
}

getSpecies(animal[0]); // => 'feline'
getSpecies(animal[1]); // => 'canine'
getSpecies(animal[2]); // => null
```

---

Per Alex's comment, for the last part, you could use [partial function application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) or you could [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the `lookUp` function.

```
const lookUp = x => y => y.hasOwnProperty(x) ? y[x] : null;
const species = lookUp('species');
species(animal[0]); // => 'feline'
species(animal[1]); // => 'canine'
species(animal[2]); // => null
```

Comment: Once the OP gets the hang of it, they can use a generic partial wrapper function to achieve the bottom function.

Answer (score 4):

You can see if the property exists on the object and return it if it does.

```
function lookUp(property){
  if (animals[0].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    return animals[0][property];
  }
}
```

You could use `in` too, but it will walk the *prototype chain* looking for a property. Sometimes this is what you want, but often it isn't. I would guess from your code that it isn't your intention.

Using `hasOwnProperty()` ensures the property is *directly present* on the prototype chain. If you're worried that `hasOwnProperty` could be a valid property name (like *species* is here), then use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(animals[0], property)`. This will use a *safe reference* to that function. Otherwise, JavaScript will think you meant to try and execute the value on your object with that property (which would probably be a *"somestring" is not a function* exception).

Comment: If you're worried enough to use `hasOwnProperty` over `in`, you should be worried about `hasOwnProperty` being a property as well…

Comment: @Bergi In most cases definitely. The OP appears to be learning though, so thought I'd try and make it easier. I will elaborate on the last paragraph.

Comment: I just meant that `if (property in animals[0])` would've been even easier

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I think it would be. I wrote some more parts anyway to hopefully make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adaptive lookUp function that can take an array of objects or an object as its first argument and a property to look up as the second argument.

```
var animals = [{
    "animal": "cat",
    "species": "feline",
    "likes": "yarn",
    "dislikes": "water"
}, {
    "animal": "dog",
    "species": "canine",
    "likes": "rubber balls",
    "dislikes": "thunder"
}, {
    "animal": "dog",
    "species": "canine",
    "likes": "rubber balls",
    "dislikes": "thunder"
}];


function lookUp (object, property) {
    // check for array
    if (object.constructor === Array) {
        // loop through, find values and return them
        var values = [];
        object.forEach(function (value, key) {
            if (property in value) {
                values.push(value[property]);
            }
        });
        return values;
    } else {
        // otherwise, check for a property and return the value
        return (property in object) ? object[property] : false;
    }
}

lookUp(animals, 'species');         // => [ "feline", "canine", "canine" ]
lookUp(animals[0], 'species');      // => "feline"
lookUp(animals, 'fakeProperty');    // => []
lookUp(animals[0], 'fakeProperty'); // => false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var animal = '[{"animal":"cat","species":"feline","likes":"yarn","dislikes":"water"},{"animal": "dog","species": "canine","likes": "rubber balls","dislikes": "thunder"}]';

var animals = JSON.parse(animal);

function myCheck(e) {
  for (key in animals) {
     for (keys in animals[key]) {
        if (keys == e) {
            console.log(keys);
        }
     }
  }
}

myCheck('species');
```

Taking dynamic objects may be. In the above example you can loop through and check if your key is the one you want. Then logging your key or you may do specific action you want. Hope this helps